# c++ copying console values to a csv

Tags: c++, csv

New in C++ and I am trying to copy the values that I read on my console after opening a .csv file to another .csv file that I want to create. Unfortunately it copies only the last value, not the whole. Any help? thanks very much!

```
int main()
{  
ifstream filetocopy("ecommerce.csv");
int d;
while(filetocopy>>d){
cout << d << endl;}

ofstream numbers("testing.csv");
        numbers << d << endl;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here.

First, you didn't create the `ofstream` to output until after you had already used and discarded most of your data.

Second, in the `while` loop, all you did was write your data to the standard output and not to file.

To correct the problem, you need to move the `ofstream` initialization before the `while` loop and move `numbers << d << endl;` into the loop.

Comment: thanks for answer. appreciated. yes, actually this is what i did.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious problems with your approach:

1) You create the output file after you read the entire input file which means you write only the last value to the output file.

2) Even if you fix 1) you would still write the csv values in a wrong order to the output file. Suggestion: read line by line -> print the line on the console -> write the line to the file.

Here's a simple solution to your problem (just an example you can improve it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main () {

   std::ifstream filetocopy("ecommerce.csv");
   std::ofstream numbers("testing.csv");
   std::string line;

   while(std::getline(filetocopy, line)) {
      std::cout << line << std::endl;
      numbers << line << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and the "getline" tip! appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Think of your ifstream as like an old VCR tape. As you are printing out characters with that while loop

```
while(filetocopy>>d){
cout << d << endl;}
```

your ifstream finished "playing". Every loop d gets a new frame of the tape and prints it out. So the tapehead is at the end, and now d is just holding onto the last frame of the credits. So when you write it to your new csv, that's the only value it has left.

Try not printing out all those values first.